# Derivation of inequality $\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}<\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}$ in proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

[image]

I don't understand how it went from line four to five in the proof?
Do you need to use induction? We haven't covered it yet.

Comment: It's just $\;\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+2)\cdot(n+2)}<\frac{1}{(n+1) \cdot (n+2)}\,$.

Comment: And using partial fraction decomposition $\frac{1}{(n+1)  (n+2)}=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}$

Answer (score 0):

Since the denominators are positive, the inequality is equivalent to

(n + 1)(n + 2) < $(n + 2)(n + 2)^2 - (n + 1)(n + 2)^2 = (n + 2)^2.$

by multiplying both sides of the inequality with the denominators.

Answer (score 0):

**Base case**: Assuming $n \ge 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I would suggest a proof by induction.
If we let 
$$p(n):=\frac{1}{\left(n+2\right)^2} \lt \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}$$
Then $p(1)$ is true, since 
$$\frac{1}{\left(1+2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{9} \lt \frac{1}{1+1} - \frac{1}{1+2} = \frac{1}{6}$$
**Induction hypothesis**: Assuming $p(n)$ is true for $n=k$, then
$$\frac{1}{\left(k+2\right)^2} \lt \frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k+2}$$
Setting $n=k+1$, $p(k+1)$ can be found as follows:
$$\frac{1}{\left(k+1+2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\left(k+3\right)^2}=\frac{1}{k^2+6k+9}=\frac{1}{(k^2+5k+6)+k+3}$$
Now $$\frac{1}{(k^2+5k+6)+k+3} \lt \frac{1}{k^2+5k+6}$$ since $k \ge 0$.

Therefore, factoring and using partial fractions:
$$\frac{1}{\left(k+3\right)^2} \lt \frac{1}{k^2+5k+6}=\frac{1}{(k+2)(k+3)}= \frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}$$
Which can be alternatively written as
$$\frac{1}{\left[\left(k+1\right) + 2\right]^2} \lt \frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)+1}-\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right) +2}$$
Hence $p(k) \Rightarrow p(k+1)$

Therefore by the principle of mathematical induction $p(n)$ as defined above is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.